# In PowerShell, everytime I execute the script the array gets bigger

Tags: powershell

So I'm starting with PowerShell and this is odd to me. I put a breakpoint in the last line and when I run the script $newArray is "abc" then it pauses in Write-Output and I stop the debugger. If I run it again, $newArray is "abcabc" and so on. For one, I think I'm doing something wrong as this behavior is so weird to me, like it stores in memory despite of stopping the debugger. And secondly I would expect $newArray to be an array and not a single string with the values concatenated. Any clues?

```
$array = "a", "b", "c";
$newArray;
foreach ($item in $array )
{
    $newArray += $item
}
Write-Output "Just before ending script";
```

Comment: `$newArray = @()`. [about_arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7)

Comment: you never set `$NewArray` to be blank. [*grin*] thus it will always accumulate until you clear what is in memory.

Comment: What @Ash said. This caching mechanism is one of the oddities of PS that caught me off-guard when I started using it too.

Comment: Awesome, that was it! Now what about the letter concatenations? I need multiple items instead of a single string, at least a single string is shown when I inspect the variable while the debugger is paused. "abc" instead of "a", "b", "c"

Comment: @user33276346 - the letter to string-of-letters thing happens because you never force the `$NewArray` to be any specific type. so, when you add a string to the blank $Var, it becomes a STRING var. then, when you add another thing that can be coerced to a string ... it gets added to the existing string. [*grin*] ///// the fix is to force the new $Var to be an array. the simplest is to declare it as such, thus ... `[array]$NewArray = @()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- **In order to use `+=` to iteratively build up an *array*, you must (re)*initialize* the target variable as an *empty array*: `$newArray = @()`**; see the bottom section for what happens if you don't.

  - Re **repeated *debugging passes***: unfortunately, both the [obsolescent Windows PowerShell ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) run in the *same* session, so that **subsequent invocations can be affected by the state of previous ones**. However, the Visual Studio PowerShell extension can be configured to **use a *new* session every time** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57927137/45375).
- That said, **it's usually better *not* to use `+=`, because it is inefficient**: it requires creating a *new* array behind the scenes in every iteration, because .NET arrays are *immutable* data structures (in terms of element count).

  - In your simple case, you could simply use the following to create a (shallow) copy of `$array`, via **`@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--)**, which implicitly clones an array:

    - `$newArray = @($array)`
  - If you need to perform an operation on each element of the source array, you can **take advantage of the fact that you can use a `foreach` loop *as an expression*, which implicitly collects the iterations' outputs in an array** - assuming that there's more than one output:

    - `[array] $newArray = foreach ($item in $array) { $item + '!' }`
    - Note the `[array]` type constraint, which ensures that `$newArray` receives an array even if the `foreach` loop happens to output just *one* object; alternatively, you could have wrapped the loop into `@(...)`

---

**How `+=` works:**

In short: **if the *first* value you add to an uninitialized variable with `+=` is a *string*, that string is stored as-is, and all subsequent `+=` operations perform *string concatenation***; specifically:

- `$newArray += $item` is syntactic sugar for `$newArray = $newArray + $item`.
- If `$newArray` has not been defined, its *implied* value is `$null`<sup>[1]</sup>
- Since your `$item` values are strings (`[string]`), `$newArray += $item` in the first iteration amounts to `$newArray = $null + "a"`, which assigns `"a"` - a single *string* - to `$newArray` (with a `[string]` RHS, `$null` on the LHS is treated like an *empty string*, performing *string concatenation* that effectively returns the RHS string in this case).
- The second iteration amounts to `$newArray = "a" + "b"`, which - given that the LHS is a *string* - again performs *string concatenation*, so that `$newArray` contains `"ab"` afterwards.
- The third (and any hypothetical subsequent iterations) simply *keep appending* to the string stored in `$newArray`.

**Generally speaking:**

- In the *first* `+=` iteration of `$initiallyUninitialized += <value>`, `$null + <value>` is evaluated, which stores `<value>` in `$initiallyUninitialized` and effectively types it as *whatever type `<value>` happens to be*.
- In subsequent `+=` iterations, the then-current type of the `$initiallyUninitialized` value determines the result of the implied `$initiallyUninitialized + <value>` operation - which *typically*, but *not necessarily*, preserves that type:

  - The type may automatically *widen* in the case of a *numeric type*:

    - `$a += [int]::MaxValue; $a += [int]::MaxValue` - `$a` is now of type `[double]`.
  - The operation may *fail* with a statement-terminating error if the `+` operation cannot be performed:

    - `$a += Get-Date; $a += Get-Date` - causes a statement-terminating *error*, because two `[datetime]` instances cannot be *added* (`+`).

---

<sup>[1] This applies by default (`Set-StrictMode -Off`); with `Set-StrictMode -Version 1` or higher, you'd actually get a statement-terminating *error*.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Setting an array's value to `@()` will clear it

**Example**: Add `$newArray =  @();` to the end of the script

Do you want it to keep the full list in one of the arrays or do you want it cleared every time you run it?

Comment: I understood now that the default behavior is to keep a some kind of cache, but with using $() I can reset it. What I wonder is how to make the add mechanism work as adding one item instead of merging the strings into a single string as it is doing now.

Comment: Adding `$newArray =  @()` to the _end_ of the script solves the problem for _subsequent_ debugging passes, but not for the _initial_ one, where - instead of building up an _array_ - _string concatenation_ happens due to `$newArray` never having been _initialized_.