# Powershell - Find # of nested folders in long file path of a directory

Tags: powershell, subdirectory, depth

Can anyone help me w/ a code puzzle in powershell?  I'm trying to look at a specific directory on several remote servers, and find the deepest nested subfolder in that directory and then count number of parent folders.  Pseudo code below.

1. $servers = get-content (list of servers) and $path = (targetdir on remote machine)
2. for each $s in $servers:
3. find the longest path
4. count the # of \ (to identify # of subfolders)
5. Write output to file $Servername $countOfNestedFolders

Sorry I'm just good enough w/ posh to be a little dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a slight variant of the "count the path parts" solutions. [*grin*] it counts the *delimiters*. if your paths are UNC paths OR local paths, this will still give you the deepest nested dir.

however, it will not work with mixed UNC [`\\SysName\ShareName`] and local [`c:\`] paths.

also, it does not remove the starting dir from the result.

also also, i am unsure how *you* want to `count number of parent folders`. so i just posted the delimiter count.

what it does ...

- sets the top dir to work from
- gets the dir delimiter char
- creates a regex escaped version of that char
- grabs all the dirs in the target dir tree
- sorts [in descending order] them by the string length of what is left over when you remove everything *except* the dir delimiters
- grabs the 1st of those dirs
- displays the `.FullName` of that dir
- displays the number of dir delimiters in the above string

the code ...

```
$TargetTopDir = $env:APPDATA
$DirDelim = [System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar
$RegexDD = [regex]::Escape($DirDelim)

$DirList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $TargetTopDir -Directory -Recurse

$DeepestNestedDir = ($DirList |
    Sort-Object {$_.FullName -replace "[^$RegexDD]"} -Descending)[0]

$DeepestNestedDir.FullName
'DirDelimCount = {0}' -f ($DeepestNestedDir.FullName -replace "[^$RegexDD]").Length
```

output ...

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\shkjhmpc.default\extensions\{e2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103}\chrome\calendar-gd\locale\gd\calendar\dialogs
DirDelimCount = 15
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're trying to find the biggest count, it sounds like you'll want to do a comparative. Basically, start with a size of 0 - if the folder you're looking at is bigger than that, then it becomes the biggest. You do this for all the folders until you're left with the biggest folder. Note, this method won't work if there are any ties, but it doesn't sound like that's what you're looking for. I should add this is the main code for looking at a single computer. You can wrap a `foreach {$server in $servers}` around this for multiple servers.

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Directory" -Directory -Recurse
$n = 0
$biggest = ""
foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
    $splitout = $folder.FullName.split("\")
    if ($splitout.count -gt $n)
    {
        $n = $splitout.count
        $biggest = $folder
    }
}

Write-host "Count $n - $biggest"
```

Comment: This got me on the right track; thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your core problem:

For a given `$path`, you can find the *maximum directory depth* in its subtree  - expressed as the number of path separators (`\` on Windows, `/` on Unix) plus one in the *full* path of the most deeply nested subdirectories inside `$path` - as follows:

```bsh
# Outputs the number of path components of the most deeply nested folder in $path.
(Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Directory | 
   Measure-Object -Maximum { ($_.FullName -split '[\\/]').Count }
).Maximum
```

Note: If you wanted to know the *relative* depth - relative to `$path`, add `-Name` to the `Get-ChildItem` call and replace `$_.FullName` with `$_` inside the script block (`{ ... }`) passed to `Measure-Object`. A result of `0` then means that `$path` has no subdirectories at all, `1` means that there are only immediate subdirectories, `2` means that the immediate subdirectories have (only) subdirectories themselves, ...

- `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory $path` outputs all subdirectories (`-Directory`) in the entire subtree of (`-Recurse`) of directory `$path`; add `-Force` to include hidden subdirs. - see [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem).
- `Measure-Object -Maximum { ($_.FullName -split '[\\/]').Count }` calculates the count of path separators (`[\\/]` is a regex that matches both a single `\` and `/` char.) in each directory's full path (`$_.FullName`) - using a *script block* `{...}` as the (implied) `-Property` argument inside of which `$_` represents the input path at hand - and determines the maximum (`-Maximum`); given that [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Measure-Object) outputs a [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo) instance, the raw maximum value is accessed via the `.Maximum` property.

---

All incidental tasks - applying this calculation to multiple servers, writing the results to server-specific files - can be accomplished with the usual cmdlets ([`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content), [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object), [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Set-Content) or [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Out-File) / `>`).

---

#### A faster alternative:

The above command is concise and PowerShell-idiomatic, but somewhat slow.
Here's a significantly faster alternative that uses LINQ and .NET APIs directly:

```
# Note: Makes sure that $path is a *full* path, because .NET's current
#       directory usually differs from PowerShell's.
1 + [Linq.Enumerable]::Max(
  ([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories(
    $path, '*', 'AllDirectories'
  ) -replace '[^\\/]').ForEach('Length')
)
```

Note: The above invariably includes *hidden* directories too. In .NET Core / .NET 5+, `[System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories()` now provides an [additional overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories#System_IO_Directory_GetDirectories_System_String_System_String_System_IO_EnumerationOptions_) that provides more control over the enumeration.

---

#### *Listing* the maximum-depth directories too:

If you want not just to calculate the maximum depth, but also want to *list* all directories that have the maximum depth (note that there can be more than one):

```
# Sample input path.
# Note: Makes sure that $path is a *full* path, because .NET's current
#       directory usually differs from PowerShell's.
$path = $PWD

# Extract all directories with the max. depth using Group-Object:
# Group by the calculated depth and extract the last group, which relies on
# Group-Object outputting the results sorted by grouping criteria.
$maxDepthGroup = 
  [System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories($path, '*', 'AllDirectories') | 
    Group-Object { ($_ -split '[\\/]').Count } |
      Select-Object -Last 1

# Construct the output object.
[pscustomobject] @{
  MaxDepth = $maxDepthGroup.Values[0] # The grouping criterion, i.e. the depth.
  MaxDepthDirs = $maxDepthGroup.Group # The paths comprising the group.
}
```

The output is a custom object with `.MaxDepth` and `.MaxDepthDirs` (an array of the full paths of those dirs. that have the max. depth) properties. If you pipe it to `Format-List`, you'll get something like:

```
MaxDepth     : 6
MaxDepthDirs : {/Users/jdoe/Documents/Ram Dass Audio Collection/The Path of Service, /Users/jdoe/Documents/Ram Dass Audio Collection/Conscious Aging,
               /Users/jdoe/Documents/Ram Dass Audio Collection/Cultivating the Heart of Compassion, /Users/jdoe/Documents/Cheatsheets/YAML Ain't
               Markup Language_files}
```

Answer (score 1):

This got it done; thanks again for all the help!

```
$servers = gc C:\serverlist.txt

ForEach ($server in $servers){
$folder = "\\$server\x$\share"
$TargetTopDir = $folder
$DirDelim = [System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar
$RegexDD = [regex]::Escape($DirDelim)

$DirList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $TargetTopDir -Directory -Recurse -ErrorAction 
SilentlyContinue

$DeepestNestedDir = ($DirList | Sort-Object {$_.FullName -replace "[^$RegexDD]"} - 
   Descending)[0]

$DepthCount = '{0}' -f ($DeepestNestedDir.FullName -replace "[^$RegexDD]").Length

$arrayItems = @{
    "Depth Count"      = $DepthCount - 3
    "Path Name"        = $DeepestNestedDir.FullName
    "Server Name"      = $server
}

$output= @()
$output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $arrayItems
$output | Export-CSV C:\Output.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you found the help you needed. Allow me a few tips for the future: Questions are most useful to future readers if they are focused on _one_ specific problem, which in your case would have been just the maximum-depth calculation. All surrounding tasks (looping over servers, saving in a specific format to a file) are _incidental_ to that problem, and will likely vary from reader to reader.

Comment: It's also important to fully specify the requirements up front: your question only mentions the need to _calculate_ the max. depth, not also to get the _paths_ of the specific folders that have that depth; speaking of: perhaps you're looking only for an _example_ of a maximum-depth path by selecting just _one_ of them, but note that there can be _multiple_ ones (I've added a solution to my answer that gets _all_ of them).

Comment: As for your specific code: note that `@{ ... }` is a _hashtable_, not an array, and that you can just cast it to `[pscustomobject]` to directly construct a custom object - in fact, that is necessary to guarantee that the object's properties will appear in the order specified in the hashtable when exported to a CSV file, for instance.
You don't need an array to send a single custom object to `Export-Csv`, and building up arrays iteratively with `+=` [should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63662692/45375).

Comment: Also, if you use `$servers | ForEach-Object { ...; $output } | Export-Csv ...` instead of your `foreach` loop, you'll only need a single `Export-Csv` call (without `-Append`) which is cleaner and more efficient. Note that you'll need to refer to the server at hand as `$_` inside the `ForEach-Object` script block (`{ ... }`) then. `$output` then simply _outputs_ your custom object _to the pipeline_, and `Export-Csv` then writes all output objects it receives to the target file.

Comment: @mklement0  ok thanks; some of what you're talking about is beyond my current understanding w/ powershell but I'll see if I can dig into your comments for further learning opportunities.  I appreciate the follow up.